# Bootstrap elements not working on virtual server

Tags: html, css, wampserver

I created a site using Boostrap and WAMP Server and now I am trying to move it to a virtual server, so more people could use it.

The site looks fine, but when clicking a drop-down toggle for example, it doesn't display anything, it just goes to `href="#"`

My element looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown" style="border-radius: 5px;">
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white;font-size: medium; background-color: #8A2BE2;border-radius: 5px;">Search <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity "></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="search_1" style="color:#601e9e;font-size: medium;border-radius: 5px;">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="search" style="color:#601e9e;font-size: medium;border-radius: 5px;">Other Options</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Is there anything I need to change? I moved all the files and folders.

Comment: Any JS errors on console?

Comment: @Narxx: _https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
navigation.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_

Comment: It seems the site won't work properly unless it is connected to the Internet. But this server would work locally, I wouldn't want any connection the the Internet. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work when you are not connected to the internet, because you are trying to load resources _from_ “the internet.” If you want everything to be available “offline,” then you need to embed resources such as that script mentioned in the error message _locally_ as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the bootstrap JavaScript file. Make sure you add after your footer and it should be fine. Your code should have something like this:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure ti put your script after jQuery script. Additionally, you may have this script, but it can't find the file in the specified location. Check if the file exist on your server.